# Behavior subject vs Observable error handling

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs

Im using rxJS in Angular and have a set of Behavior Subjects that are exposed as a readonly Observable

```
public _data = new BehaviorSubject<DataItem[]>([]);
public readonly data$ = this._data.asObservable();
```

now I have noticed that if I subscribe directly to the `BehaviorSubject` and there is an error it will throw the error to the console.

but if I subscribe to the Observable with same error I don't get any messages and the listener is then unsubscribed automatically.

I know this is the expected behavior but...

I would like to know what is the pattern to avoid code duplication on errors e.g.

```
this.myDataService.data$.subscribe(d=> throwSomeError(), e=> handleError(e));
//or use this:
this.myDataService.data$.subscribe(d=> throwSomeError()).catch(e=> handleError(e));
```

the handleError(e)

Comment: So you want  to use the same error handler multiple times without specifying it every time?

Comment: True .. That would be one option ..

Answer (score 0):

The second option will work better as BehaviorSubject will always kill the stream on an error.

Here's more info:

[How do I throw an error on a behaviour subject and continue the stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827371/how-do-i-throw-an-error-on-a-behaviour-subject-and-continue-the-stream)

Comment: thank you but this does not answer my question .. i know that its better to use `,catch(...)` but i want the default onError in all subscibers be `console.error(...)` or `throw Error(..)` how can this be achieved while subscribing to `Observable` instead of the `BehaviorSubject ` directly

Comment: p.s i don't mind the stream being killed .. that not a problem i just want a good way to see errors occur in my subscriber functions... without wrinting `.catch(..)` for every subscriber....